# Is it possible to reduce the context switch time

Tags: android, mediarecorder, context-switch

MediaRecorder.start() takes much time. Method Profiling says that 'context switch' - Inclusive Real Time is 100% and takes about 1510 ms. Is it possible to reduce it somehow?
I need it to be as fast as possible.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Context switching is the system's operation of changing focus to a different running process. The processor saves the state of the current running one and loads the state of another. Speeding up a context switch is not something you can do through Android API's.